# Why doesn't both my Polygons have a border when i use setStroke?

Tags: java, polygon, stroke

I am drawing two stars using:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
    g2.drawPolygon(xCoordOfStar, yCoordOfStar, POINTS);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
}
```

and:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {  
     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
     Star star1 = new Star(100,200,300);
     Star star2 = new Star(200,200,300);
     star1.draw(g2);
     star2.draw(g2);    
}
```

In the other class.

For some reason unknown to me, only the bigger star (`star2`) gets a thicker border, while `star1` does not get any border. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could it be because you set the stroke AFTER drawing the polygon instead of before?

Comment: do i ever feel stupid now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an ordering issue. Your second Polygon gets a border because your first Polygon called the `g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));` Comment out the first star code, the second star now also loses its border.

To fix it, you just need to rearrange the methods:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
    g2.drawPolygon(xCoordOfStar, yCoordOfStar, POINTS);
}
```